# Put badge up in the right corner - bootstrap 4

Tags: css, reactjs, bootstrap-4

I'm building a NavBar in bootstrap (using React).
I would like to put a badge up in the right corner of the button.

This is the current situation:

[image: current situation]

```
<div>
                        <button className="btn btn-primary btn-lg navbar-btn">
                            <i class="fas fa-file-invoice-dollar fa-lg"></i>
                            <span class="badge badge-success">1</span>
                        </button>
                        <button className="btn btn-primary btn-lg navbar-btn">
                            <i class="fas fa-envelope fa-lg"></i>
                        </button>
                        <button className="btn btn-primary btn-lg navbar-btn">
                            <i class="fas fa-cogs fa-lg"></i>
                        </button>
                        <button className="btn btn-outline-danger btn-lg" onClick={this.logoutClicked}>
                            <i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt fa-lg"></i>
                        </button>
                    </div>
```

And I would like to have something like this:

[image: what I want]

Comment: could you also add your css that you have?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**No extra CSS is needed.** Wrap the badge span inside a `sup`...

`<sup><span class="badge badge-success">1</span></sup>`

https://www.codeply.com/go/3vc5PlgpTe

FYI, reboot allows this to work which sets the following style on the `sup` tag...

```
sup {
    top: -.5em;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 75%;
    line-height: 0;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
```

Comment: thats more of a hack than an actual styling^^ and it wont work, if you make your icon bigger like font-size: 40px;

Comment: Why not just add `<sup>`? Why the need for the `<span>`?

Comment: @DigitalJedi do you know that reboot is included with Bootstrap and has specific superscript styling?, and *no*.. it doesn't make the font size 40px, it makes it 75% of base.

Comment: @Zim Sorry to confuse you, but thats not what i meant. Try setting a different font size for the icon like:`<i  style="font-size: 100px;" class="fas fa-envelope fa-lg"></i>` and you will see, that the `<sup>` element is no longer in the top left corner. thats why i think its a little hacky. for me this shouldnt be the accepted answer but apparently the author likes it - anyways it does what it should if you dont make the icon too big without changing the containers font-size too - accepted

Comment: Hmmm, yeah. I guess the OP doesn't expect to have 100px size fonts  in their Navbar, and wanted a simple Bootstrap solution. Also the top alignment issue against a larger icon could be resolved using the `align-top` class.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by setting `position: relative;` to the parent, and something like  `position absolute; top: -5px; right: -5px;` to the child.

```css
.includer{
 position: relative;
}

.badge.badge-success{
 background-color: yellow;
 position: absolute; 
 top: -5px;
 right: -5px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-oS3vJWv+0UjzBfQzYUhtDYW+Pj2yciDJxpsK1OYPAYjqT085Qq/1cq5FLXAZQ7Ay" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div>
  <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg navbar-btn includer">
      <i class="fas fa-file-invoice-dollar fa-lg"></i>
      <span class="badge badge-success">1</span>
  </button>
  <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg navbar-btn">
      <i class="fas fa-envelope fa-lg"></i>
  </button>
  <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg navbar-btn">
      <i class="fas fa-cogs fa-lg"></i>
  </button>
  <button class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-lg" onClick={this.logoutClicked}>
      <i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt fa-lg"></i>
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: You could utilize the `position-relative` class here instead of adding the `includer` class.

Comment: @Zim I know, but when including bootstrap, you would also need to overwrite the `top` and `right` positioning with `!important`, because it is already set in `.btn .badge`
I wanted to keep it simple. But thanks for pointing it out